# Ubuntu touch compiling: missing msm_ion.h

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, compiling, porting

I've started porting Ubuntu Touch to the LG Volt (LS740) from Boost Mobile. I have my device tree vendor blobs and kernel sources all in place, but I'm getting a compile error:

```
In file included from hardware/qcom/display/msm8226/libgralloc/ionalloc.cpp:38:0:
hardware/qcom/display/msm8226/libgralloc/ionalloc.h:33:27: fatal error: linux/msm_ion.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I have an `include` folder in my device tree. It contains the `linux` folder which includes the `msm_mdp.h` file, but it's not getting included by the compiler.

My `Android.mk` file in my device root (device/lge/x5) contains:

```
ifneq ($(filter x5,$(TARGET_DEVICE)),)

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))

endif
```

I assume that's enough code to pass the `linux` folder to the compiler, but apparently it's not working...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and I solved it by adding the path to the kernel headers to common.mk (hardware/qcom/display/msm8226/common.mk in your case):
common_includes += path_goes_here